# submission of MPI+openmp code in PBS cluster

Tags: mpi, openmp, hybrid

I am trying to submit MPI+openmp code in cluster. I am relatively new in using mpi in general. I am trying to use 2 MPI processes and 16 openmp process for each mpi process. I am using following parameters:

```
#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=16
OMP_NUM_THREADS=16
export OMP_NUM_THREADS
mpirun -np 2 --bind-to core --map-by ppr:1:node:pe=16 -x OMP_NUM_THREADS ./exe
```

But this is returning with an error saying::

```
Your job has requested more processes than the ppr for
this topology can support:
  App: ./exe
  Number of procs:  2
  PPR: 1:node
Please revise the conflict and try again.
```

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: C != C++ Tag with one, unless both are *actually* relevant.

Comment: I don't think I have access to any systems using PBS to test answers on right now. I don't suppose you can use SLURM?

Comment: Hi Rachard, Thanks for the reply. Not really, we have only PBS.. Is it a issue of architecture of nodes in the cluster ?

Comment: While there might be a general answer, I believe this question is best directed at your site admins / support. They know your batch system configuration best - and this might help them improve documentation.

Comment: There is no guarantee that PBS will give you 16+16 slots on two different hosts if there is a single host that provides at least 32 slots. Check the documentation of your specific software version on how to enforce the allocation of a different host for each chunk.

Comment: Dear Zulan & Hristo, Thanks for the answer guys .. I will do that...